# OP3 get VectorTile attributes

Tags: openlayers

I am trying to access a VectorTile layers attributes in Openlayers3 like this [example](http://openlayersbook.github.io/ch05-using-vector-layers/example-09.html). The layer is being server by '[Chubbs](https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI)'

The layer:

```
var observationLayer = new ol.layer.VectorTile({
      source: new ol.source.VectorTile({
        format: new ol.format.MVT(),
        tileGrid: ol.tilegrid.createXYZ({maxZoom: 22}),
        tilePixelRatio: 16,
        url: '/services/postgis/test_observations/geometry/vector-tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf'
      }),
      style: observationStyle
    });
```

Trying to get the attributes when the mouse hovered over the point:

```
function onMouseMove(browserEvent) {
        var coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
        var pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);

        map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) {
          // Small sub set of all the  things I have tried...
          console.log('feature:');
          console.log(feature); // returns the features!

          console.log('layer:');
          console.log(layer); // returns the layer!

          console.log('layer.getProperties():');
          console.log(layer.getProperties()); // returns the prope

          var source = layer.getSource();
          console.log('source:');
          console.log(source);

          var properties = source.getProperties();
          console.log('properties:');
          console.log(properties); // returns an empty object
        });
      }
      map.on('pointermove', onMouseMove);
```

Comment: Which informations do  you want try to retrieve?

Comment: What about `feature.getProperties()`?

Comment: @oterral In my case, I have a layer of points, each point contains attribute information such as 'id', 'name', 'date' etc.

Comment: @ahocevar Yes, I tried `feature.getProperties()`, but it only returns: id: "test_observations_geometry" instead of all of the layers attributes. If I change the layer to a GeoJSON source, then it works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I issued this [ticket](https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI/issues/126) on the '[Chubbs](https://github.com/spatialdev/PGRestAPI)' git repo and got the solution!

"By default, only the id is returned to cut down on the size of the payload/tile coming from the server. I chose to only show id rather than show all properties. You can add in the properties you'd like to have returned by adding a 'fields' querystring parameter to the end of the vector tile request URL, and using a comma separated list of your field names."

`{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf?fields=myfield1,myfield2,myfield3`